# Error Saving data into database after scanning with zxing

Tags: android, android-sqlite, zxing

What it should do: Scan a barcode with the inegrated `ZXING` and save the barcode into the app's `SQLite database`.

First I tried just scanning the barcode and display it on the screen with a `Toast-Message` so far it worked just fine.

Afterward, I added the function to insert the `barcode` into the database. since then I'm getting following error:

```
12-29 11:58:00.363 28012-28012/com.factory.future.ap_manager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.factory.future.ap_manager, PID: 28012
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }} to activity {com.factory.future.ap_manager/com.factory.future.ap_manager.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.factory.future.ap_manager/aps
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4520)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.factory.future.ap_manager/aps
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1276)
                                                                               at com.factory.future.ap_manager.MainActivity.addAP(MainActivity.java:116)
                                                                               at com.factory.future.ap_manager.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:95)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7282)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Here's the code for handling the scan result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            addAP(result.getContents());
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void addAP(String barcodeNumber) {

    int codeLength = barcodeNumber.length();
    barcodeNumber = barcodeNumber.substring(4,codeLength - 1);
    int APID = Integer.parseInt(barcodeNumber);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + APID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String title = "TestAP-" + barcodeNumber;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(APEntry.AP_ID, 13222);
    values.put(APEntry.AP_TITLE, title);

    Toast.makeText(this, APEntry.CONTENT_URI.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getContentResolver().insert(APEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

I also tried skipping the Intent to `ZXING` and directly calling the `addAP` function in the `onClick` method. Getting following error there:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.factory.future.ap_manager/aps
```

Here's a link to all the files:
[Link](https://mega.nz/#!Sl83EL5A!q-vKycStlBarAWGdl3qou0vaMIs_LzMx1skXDP3RKw8)

Comment: Check your APEntry.CONTENT_URI that seems to be incorrect somehow

Comment: Already checked. Even cross-checked with the "Pets"-App that i did while doing the Google android course on udacity. Couldn't find anything wrong with the CONTENT_URI.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
The CONTENT_URI itself war correct but in the `AndroidManifest.xml` I wrote `android:authorities="com.future.factory.ap_manager"` instead of `android:authorities="com.factory.future.ap_manager"`.
(and missed it several hundreds of times while looking at the code)